# ODOO : Run cron at a specific time

Tags: cron, odoo-10

I want to add a cron job that runs at a specific time.

I have added the cron in xml but it has `interval_number` and `interval_type`. How to make it run at a specific time of day?

```
 <record id="ir_cron_module_get_active_sr" model="ir.cron">
                <field name="name">Get Active Srs</field>
                <field eval="True" name="get_active_srs" />
                <!--<field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />-->
                <field name="interval_number">1</field>
                <field name="interval_type">days</field>
                <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
                <field eval="False" name="doall" />
                <field eval="'hr.attendance'" name="model" />
                <field eval="'get_active_srs'" name="function" />
                <field eval="'(None,)'" name="args" />
                <field name="priority">1000</field>
         </record>
```

Comment: the use of scheduler is to perform any specific action on specific time schedule in hour , years, minutes months....when you want to run scheduler?

Comment: @ADVALAKI At 12 pm everyday, that is why I wanted to know how to set specific time of execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<record id="ir_cron_module_get_active_sr" model="ir.cron">
        <field name="name">Get Active Srs</field>
        <field eval="True" name="get_active_srs" />
        <!--<field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />-->
        <field name="interval_number">1</field>
        <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00')" />
        <field name="interval_type">days</field>
        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        <field eval="False" name="doall" />
        <field eval="'hr.attendance'" name="model" />
        <field eval="'get_active_srs'" name="function" />
        <field eval="'(None,)'" name="args" />
        <field name="priority">1000</field>
</record>
```

Comment: looks like it will run everyday at 12, right? Taking todays date and adding remaining time?

Comment: Okay, I'll try and get back to you on this. Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to change the interval, although I have removed `no-update` from `data` tag and updated the module. I even removed the record from the xml but it continues to run every minute. How can I change the interval?

Comment: If I want to run every night at 12? Should I have to add     <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 24:00:00')" /> ?