# ODOO How to run automated actions at a specific time everyday

Tags: cron, odoo-10

I am trying to add a cron job that should run every day at 12 pm. I am facing a few issue and have a few doubts.

1. I was able to run it every minute but couldn't run it at a specific time.
2. How to know which timezone is expected and which timezone is set in the "nextcall" field
3. It doesnt run until I open console in the browser. How can it be done so that it runs at the server and no additional action is needed?

   ```
       <record id="ir_cron_module_get_active_sr" model="ir.cron">
           <field name="name">Get Active Srs</field>
           <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
           //<field name="interval_number">2</field>
           //<field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
           <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
           <field name="nextcall" eval="(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 12:22:00')" />
           <field name="doall" eval="True"  />
           <field name="model" eval="'sd.cron'"  />
           <field name="function" eval="'get_active_srs'" />
           <field name="args" eval="'(None,)'" />
           <field name="priority">1</field>
       </record>
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ODOO : Run cron at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671974/odoo-run-cron-at-a-specific-time)

Comment: The issue was that it was not reflecting the changes that I made. The code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are omitting this line:

```
<field name="active">True</field>
```

Functionally you can check it under `Settings --> Automation --> Scheduled Actions` with the  debut mode activated.

What I can see on your code is that this 2 lines aren't well commented (you wanted to comment them or it was a copy pasta mistake?)

```
//<field name="interval_number">2</field>
//<field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
```

Check if that's the right time you want to run the next test, it is in UCT time, you can check the UTC time in linux with `timedatectl` on a terminal (in ubuntu at least)

```
<field name="nextcall" eval="(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 12:22:00')" />
```

I don't know in what context are you using this cron, but remember that the model must be the one that contains the function that you are calling. So, be sure that `sd.cron` has the method `get_active_srs`

```
<field name="model" eval="'sd.cron'"  />
```

At the end, if you are not passing any arguments you can omit this line

```
<field name="args" eval="'(None,)'" />
```

Comment: How to remove the cron job? I removed the data record and upgraded the module, still it runs. The settings option is not added so I cannot use `Settings --> Automation --> Scheduled Actions`. How to remove cron at once?

Comment: You have several options, but I will mention just 3 options:
1) Uninstall the module and reinstall it

2) With database, first `SELECT id,name,model FROM ir_cron;` then  `DELETE FROM ir_cron WHERE id=X;`

3) Login as admin, and activate the debug mode.

Comment: No, but it's an easy option. I recommend you to use the `settings` option with debug. Your server is on production or it's local?

Comment: Its local for development but will be pushed to production.  I tried the database option and it works without any problem. And I added the `active` field, dont know if it worked because of that but its working. Thank you for quick response.