# Odoo: cron job set nextcall with specific time of the day not working

Tags: python, cron, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to set nextcall for cron job and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671974/odoo-run-cron-at-a-specific-time).

```
<odoo>
<record id="cron_job" model="ir.cron">
    ...
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">days</field>
    <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 10:00:00')" />
</record>
```

but when I check from Scheduled Actions, instead of having 10:00:00 today it became 18:00:00.

What is the correct way to set the nextcall with the exact time without the need of modifying it from the Settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is something you have to understand, Odoo get psql server time when you insert a record field of datetime. This server time is UTC time, and each time you open a browser, that server time will be converted into local time according to geo ip.
This mean if you open this record in psql, the nextcall field will be 10AM.
But in your browser, it is automatically converted into your timezone.

Comment: does this mean if the cron job started, the time from the Scheduled Actions which is 18:00:00 will be automatically converted to local timezone and whenever the cron job is running any automated actions will be received at 10AM?

Comment: no, cron start at 10 AM UTC, that means 6PM in your local time, just as what you see

Comment: is it possible to convert utc time to local and so that the displayed time from the browser will be 10 AM?

Comment: I haven't done the exact same job before, but I did some timezone import data to database. My answer is you should consider learning datetime module from python pre-install libraries. Something like timezone and timedelta may help you.